# How to combine three multiple sql queries into one output

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to combine below sql queries to get one single output

```
SELECT reg.REGION_ID, count(*) as totalDist FROM REGION reg LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGANIZATION org
ON org.FK_REGION=reg.REGION_ID group by reg.REGION_ID;

SELECT reg.REGION_ID, count(*) as activeTotal FROM REGION reg LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGANIZATION org
ON org.FK_REGION=reg.REGION_ID and org.ACTIVE=1 group by reg.REGION_ID;

select u.Region_ID, count(*) as userCount from USER u where u.ORG_ID IN(
 Select org.ORG_ID from ORGANIZATION org where org.FK_REGION IN(select REGION_ID from REGION reg))  group by ORG_ID;
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

Add `UNION` between them:

```
SELECT reg.REGION_ID, COUNT(*) AS totalDist
FROM REGION reg 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGANIZATION org
  ON org.FK_REGION=reg.REGION_ID 
GROUP BY reg.REGION_ID
UNION
SELECT reg.REGION_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM REGION reg
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGANIZATION org
  ON org.FK_REGION=reg.REGION_ID 
 AND org.ACTIVE=1
GROUP BY reg.REGION_ID
UNION
SELECT u.Region_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM `USER` u
WHERE u.ORG_ID IN(SELECT org.ORG_ID 
                  FROM ORGANIZATION org
                  WHERE org.FK_REGION IN(SELECT REGION_ID FROM REGION reg))
GROUP BY ORG_ID;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT r.REGION_ID, s1.totalDist, s2.activeTotal, s3.useCount
FROM REGION r
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT reg.REGION_ID, COUNT(*) AS totalDist
  FROM REGION reg 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGANIZATION org
   ON org.FK_REGION=reg.REGION_ID 
  GROUP BY reg.REGION_ID
) AS s1
 ON r.REGION_ID = s1.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT reg.REGION_ID, COUNT(*) AS activeTotal
  FROM REGION reg
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGANIZATION org
    ON org.FK_REGION=reg.REGION_ID 
   AND org.ACTIVE=1
  GROUP BY reg.REGION_ID
) AS s2
  ON r.REGION_ID = s2.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT u.Region_ID, COUNT(*) AS  useCount 
  FROM `USER` u
  WHERE u.ORG_ID IN(SELECT org.ORG_ID 
                  FROM ORGANIZATION org
                  WHERE org.FK_REGION IN(SELECT REGION_ID FROM REGION reg))
) AS s3
  ON r.REGION_ID = s3.REGION_ID;
```

Comment: yep, the answer is close Thanks, I have tried the same before the problem is its giving or showing only two columns, I actually need a result in table with four columns regionid, totalDist, activeTotal, useCount